# Split the string '1/10/2/20/3/30/4/40' into two columns check body for more details

Tags: sql-server, split

```
string = '1/10/2/20/3/30/4/40'
output = col1  |   col2
           1   |    10
           2   |    20
           3   |    30
           4   |    40
```

I tried below code:

```
DECLARE @TEXT VARCHAR(60) = '1/10/2/20/3/30/4/40', @POSITION INT=1
CREATE TABLE #TEMP(VAL1 INT,VAL2 INT)
WHILE (LEN(@TEXT) >= @POSITION)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES(SUBSTRING(@TEXT,@POSITION,1),SUBSTRING(@TEXT,@POSITION+2,2))
  SET @POSITION = @POSITION+5
END

SELECT * FROM #TEMP
```

this is giving the output but this is more like hard coded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next time please state your SQL-Server's version...

The following solution works with almost any version, if you are at v2016+ there might be better approaches. Try this out:

```
DECLARE @TEXT VARCHAR(60) = '1/10/2/20/3/30/4/40';

WITH Casted(ToXml) AS
(
    SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(@TEXT,'/','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)
)
,TallyOddNumbers(OddNumber) AS
(   
    SELECT TOP((SELECT ToXml.value('count(/x)','int')/2 FROM Casted)) (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)))*2-1 FROM master..spt_values
)
SELECT ToXml.value('/x[sql:column("OddNumber")][1]','int') AS Col1
      ,ToXml.value('/x[sql:column("OddNumber")+1][1]','int') AS Col1
FROM Casted
CROSS JOIN TallyOddNumbers;
```

The idea in short:

- The first cte "Casted" will create an XML from your string.
- The second cte "TallyOddNumbers" will use `ROW_NUMBER()` against `master..spt_values` (just any larger set is okay here) to create a set of running odd numbers
- The computed `TOP` clause will use `XML.value()` with `count()` to find the needed number of element pairs.
- The final query will use the tally to grab the values by their positions.

Hint: You can use the code above simply together with `INSERT` in order to get the set in a persistant table.

### UPDATE  for version 2016+

In your own answer you are using `string_split()` (which is not a good idea due to the non-guaranteed sort order). But this points to a version of v2016+.

You might try this alternativ approach

```
DECLARE @TEXT VARCHAR(60) = '1/10/2/20/3/30/4/40';


WITH ToJson(j) AS(SELECT CONCAT('[',REPLACE(@TEXT,'/',','),']'))
SELECT p.Col1
      ,p.Col2
FROM
(
    SELECT A.[key] /2 AS GroupIndex
          ,CONCAT('Col',A.[key]%2 +1) AS ColumnName
          ,A.[value] AS TheValue 
    FROM ToJson
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j) A
) t
PIVOT
(
    MAX(TheValue) FOR ColumnName IN(Col1,Col2)
) p;
```

The idea in short:

- The cte will transform your CSV-list to a JSON array
- We use `OPENJSON` to read this array
- the `key` is the elements position. Together with `%2` (modulo operator) we get a computed, alternating column name
- Finally we can use `PIVOT` to spread your values into `Col1` and `Col2`.
- The `A.[key] /2` will use a trick with integer divisions to create one number per group (otherwise you would see just to last row).

Comment: Okay, This was Helpful one. I learnt something new in SQL. I just have a doubt that using cross join is bad practice right?

Comment: @ChiragSheth, No `CROSS JOIN` is not "bad practice". It is a simple *each-with-each* join (cartesian product). In this case we have a guaranteed one-liner in the cte `Casted`. The `CROSS JOIN` is the easiest way to bind the tally's set to this single line in order to repeat it as often as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I tried by creating temporory tables. And adding single digit into one temp table, and non-single digit into another temp table. And putting values of both table into another temp table.

Code:
     Note: @series is string I passed.

```
select value into #value from string_split(@series,'/')

create table #position(var int identity(1,1),var1 int)

insert into #position(var1)    
select value from #value    where value like '_'

create table #position2(var int,var2 int)

insert into #position2(var2)   
select value from #value where value not like '_'

create table #final(var1 int,var2 int)

insert into #final(var1,var2)    
select p1.var1,p2.var2 from #position p1                
      join #position2 p2 on p1.var=p2.var

select * from #final
```

Comment: Chirag, this should be part of your question... Use the edit option below the question to change this. In general: A good question includes sample data, expected ouptut and your own attempts together with some explanation. All this is best served as [mcve] (a *self-running* and *stand-alone* sample).

Comment: Just looking at your code once again I see `string_split()`. This is **very dangerous**... This function does not guarantee to return the elements in the expected sort order...